# Why is this SpringJdbc is returning null?

Tags: spring, jdbc, null, dto

I have a DTO class

```
public class A {
    private String Name;
    private int Id;
    private long superId;

    //Getters and setters omitted
}
```

A wrapper class

```
public class B {
    private A account;
    private List<A> underlyingAccounts;

    //Getters and setters omitted
}
```

Now i have DAO class running a stored procedure with springJdbc with takes in the parameter of superId. which im getting it from a SQL_STATEMENT query separately.

```
@Repository
public class DaoImpl implements Dao {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public String getSuperId(){
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL_STATEMENT, String.class);            
    }

    public B getStandAloneAccountInfo(String id) {
        B infoModel = new B();

        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate
                    .getDataSource()).withProcedureName("getAccountInfo");

        SqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("superId", getSuperId());

        simpleJdbcCall.returningResultSet("parameterResult", new RowMapper() {
            public A mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                A account = new A();
                account.setName(resultSet.getString("Name"));
                account.setId(resultSet.getInt("ID"));
                return account;
            }
        });
        Map<String, Object> map = simpleJdbcCall.execute(parameterSource);
        List<B> result = (List<B>) map.get("parameterResult");

        return infoModel ;
    }
}
```

My question is one how to return account as a wrapper of model class. Im using a wrapper as some id could have multiple accounts and i want to return them as a list. And why is this throwing null? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if we had a stacktrace to work from. Without one this is very hard to debug.

Comment: It wasn't giving any errors. But i debugged it and found error. Thanks though!